# Como envioel valor de un input tipo file por ajax para usarlo en el controllador

Tags: ajax, laravel, formularios, controller

Tengo un formulario el cual es envia los datos a el controlador por medio de ajax

```js
<script>
    function save() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{{url('/user/new')}}',
            data: {
                startDate: $('#startDate').val(),
                nota: $('#nota').val(),
                endDate: $('#endDate').val(),
                file: $('#file').val()
            }
            ,
            success: function (data) {
                // location.reload();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                showAjaxErrors(data, 'error_msg');
                markError(['startDate', 'endDate', 'nota']);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

```html
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/save', 'files'=> 'true'), ['id' => 'absenceForm']) }}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::text('startDate', null, ['class' => 'form-control date', 'placeholder' => 'Fecha Inicio', 'id' => 'startDate', 'title' => 'Fecha inicio']) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::text('endDate', null, ['class' => 'form-control date', 'placeholder' => 'Fecha Fin', 'id' => 'endDate', 'title' => 'Fecha Fin']) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::textarea('nota', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Nota', 'id' => 'note', 'rows' => '3', 'title' => 'Nota']) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::file('file'),['id'=>'file']}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    {{ Form::button('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'onClick' => 'save()']) }}
</div>
{{Form::close()}}
```

Al hacer`dd($request->all());` solo me muestra

array:5 [
  "startDate" => "21-11-2018"
  "nota" => "NOta de prueba"
  "endDate" => "21-11-2018"
]

Pero el valor del campo file no me lo muestra
Y si hago `dd($request->file('file'));` me muestra NULL

¿Como obtengo el valor del archivo para usar en el controlador?

Comment: Referencia: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#files

Según entiendo debes definir el atributo name al input file para luego recepcionar en el controller.

Es decir...

$file = $request->file('file');

Comment: @EliasCatalan como comentaba al hacer dd($request->file('file') como resultado obtengo NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hasta donde recuerdo nunca me ha funcionado enviar Files a Laravel asi directamente, lo que yo hago es crear un formdata.

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("startDate", $('#startDate').val());
...
formData.append("file", fileInputElement.files[0]);
```

Y si mal no recuerdo debes cambiar un par de configuration en el Ajax, para que quede algo así (si mi memoria no me falla)

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '{{url('/user/new')}}',
  data: formData,
  processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
  contentType: false,   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
  success: function (data) {
    // location.reload();
  },
  error: function (data) {
    showAjaxErrors(data, 'error_msg');
    markError(['startDate', 'endDate', 'nota']);
  }
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData

Comment: No trataba de enviar el file a Laravel, lo que trataba era de enviar los datos de ese file al controlador y esa informacion almacenarla. Y me funciono, tomando en cuenta el append y adaptandolo al codigo datos.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);